# Как отобразить в react с помощью moment js текущее время

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import moment from 'moment'

export default class Time extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="header_clock"></div>
        )
    }
}
```

дальше не понятно как выводить в div header_clock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробовали вот так?

**[ссылка](https://codesandbox.io/s/9448pqwy2w) на CodeSandbox**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Moment from "react-moment";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Moment format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm" interval={1000} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: класс. а как убрать секунды? мне нужны только часы и минуты

Comment: @stiv, обновил. Если хотите убрать дату, то просто уберите `YYYY-MM-DD` P.S. CodeSandbox всё тот же.

Comment: Интервал обновления времени наверное нужно будет увеличить? Какое значение порекомендуете ?

Comment: @stiv, лучше не увеличивать, т.к. при заходе у пользователя может быть, например: 13:40:32, а мы будем задавать обновление, допустим, раз в минуту, что не правильно, т.к. время на часах измениться уже на 13:41:00, а у нас все ещё будет 13:40, так что лучше оставить значение 1000

Comment: Кстати заметил что если заходить в react dev tools, то пользоваться не удобно т.к обновляется каждую секунду и смотреть код неудобно, постоянно выкидывает наверх(а именно props http://prntscr.com/mgrl2a)

Comment: @stiv, остановите обновление, а на продакшене и забудьте поставить обратно.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import moment from 'moment'

export default class Time extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
            currentTime: moment().format()
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.intervalIdx = setInterval(() => this.setState ({
            currentTime: moment().format()
        }), 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.intervalIdx);
    }

    render () {
        constructor { currentTime } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="header_clock">{currentTime}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: а как сделать автообновление?

Comment: Добавил автообновление на основе `setInterval`, он не является точным и может тротлить если страница неактивна, но я не увидел условия про точный таймер. Если Вам нужен точный таймер, то нужно переписать на `setTimeout` в рекурсии.